# Set all markers in a featureGroup draggable = false

Tags: leaflet

simple question: 
How can i set the draggability from all markers in a featureGroup on false?

Thanks, greets!

Comment: what have you tried yourself and where did it go wrong? Please read [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply loop through all markers within the Feature Group using the [`eachLayer()` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-eachlayer), make sure the passed layer is a marker, and disable the [dragging functionality](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-dragging) using the [marker interaction handler](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-interaction-handlers).

```js
myFeatureGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
    layer.dragging.disable();
  }
});
```

You can also re-enable the dragging functionality using [`marker.dragging.enable()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#ihandler).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/108/ (built on answer of [Get multiple Markers in Leaflet](http://Get%20multiple%20Markers%20in%20Leaflet)).